# v8dotnet -- can't load v8.net.proxy.interface

Tags: c#, v8, embedded-v8, v8.net

I'm trying to write a hello world program that prints some basic js to the console using v8dotnet.

I have a simple application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using V8.Net;

namespace v8test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var v8engine = new V8Engine();
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'V8.Net.Proxy.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An operation is not legal in the current state. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131509)

I have put all the dll's that come with the binary's in my bin/debug folder and added the reference V8.NET dll (like the documentation described).  I've tried multiple combinations of setting x86 or x64 and setting the version of dotnet to 4.0.

I made sure i have the visual c++ 2012 redistribution installed.  Regardless of what I try, I can't seem to get it to work.  Any help?

Comment: Don't put the binaries in `bin\Debug` folder. Put them somewhere else and then add reference. When you build the project, the build process will copy the required binaries in `bin\Debug` folder.

Comment: same error.  it says could not find <file> but my DLL's are called <file>_x86 and <file>_x64 ...could it be related to that?

Comment: Just to add, when it copies dll's into the debug folder, it only copies v8.NET.dll and V8.Net.SharedTypes.dll

Comment: Documentation is strange - anyway, the zip file seems to come with `x86` and `x64` folders. Dont copy the content of those folders to `bin\Debug` - instead copy the whole folder as is. Meaning, you should have folders `\bin\Debug\x86` and `bin\Debug\x64`.

Comment: I tried that, but I still seem to get the same error, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those having this same problem, it turns out is a security issue.

the right setup is to have V8.Net and V8.Net.SharedTypes reference and copy x86  / x64 folders into the bin/debug folder.

For each of the DLL's you have "unblock" them by right clicking and clicking properties on each of the DLL's.

Comment: It's better to unblock the zip file before unzipping so you don't have to do that for each file. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of V8.NET out that no longer uses sub-folders.  Also, there is no longer a v8.dll, since it is statically linked into the V8.NET C++ projects.

CodePlex is shut down, so the new source is here: https://github.com/rjamesnw/v8dotnet